# Live Text from webcam in MacOS

Tags: macos, preview, webcam, text-input, ocr

Getting used to [Live Text](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/use-live-text-iphcf0b71b0e/15.0/ios/15.0) [image] via *tap menu in text inputs* on iOS<sup>1</sup> I'd like to use it the same ubiquitous way on macOS, but there you must use the [Preview app](https://support.apple.com/guide/preview/prvw625a5b2c) (link [via](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/440714)). So you have to 1st take a photo using PhotoBooth.app, navigate to `~/Pictures/Photo Booth Library/Pictures/` and open the file in Preview until you can at last select the text you want.

Is there a way to use the webcam the same way as on iOS devices, that opens a window with the live webcam image and the possibility to select text from it?


A nice way would be to make it available via *Input menu in menu bar* where you can also access the [Character Viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-emoji-and-symbols-on-mac-mchlp1560/12.0/mac/12.0) for Emojis or somehow trigger it via a script or Automator.

---

<sub>1) Seems to be documented nowhere</sub>